# Check for function existance on other type using C++ concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Does anybody know how to make a C++ concept `T` such that the function `g` is only defined for arguments `t` with type `T` if there exist an overload of `f` in `B` that accepts an argument `t`?

```
struct A1 {};
struct A2 {};
struct B {
    void f(A1 a1) {}
};
void g(T t) {
    B b;
    b.f(t);
}
```

As an example, I want to define a `to_string` for everything that `std::stringstream` accepts, and define something like

```
std::string to_string(T t) {
    std::stringstream ret;
    ret << t;
    return ret.str();
}
```

All examples on concepts deal with the easier case of requiring the existance of a function on a type, while in this case we want to check existance of a function on another type.

Comment: Should `b.func(t);` be `b.f(t)`?

Comment: is T the type? The concept? The requirement?

Comment: @einpoklum T is the concept. A concept is a set of requirements to my understanding.

Comment: @Carucel: Ok, edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two different *type* placeholders in a single concept, to require both the existence of a member function for an instance of one of the type placeholders, as well as the argument to said member function to match the type of another placeholder. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
concept HasMemFnConstFoo = requires(const T t, const U u) {
    t.foo(u);
};

template<typename U>
struct Bar {
    template <typename T>
    static void bar(const T& t)
    {
        if constexpr (HasMemFnConstFoo<T, U>) { t.foo(U{}); }
        else { std::cout << "foo() not defined\n"; }
    }
};

struct A1 {};
struct A2 {};
struct B1 {
    void foo(const A1&) const { std::cout << "B1::foo()\n"; }
};
struct B2 {
    void foo(const A1&) { std::cout << "B2::foo()\n"; }
};
struct B3 {
    void foo(A1&) const { std::cout << "B3::foo()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Bar<A1>::bar(B1{});  // B1::foo()
    Bar<A2>::bar(B1{});  // foo() not defined
    Bar<A1>::bar(B2{});  // foo() not defined [note: method constness]
    Bar<A2>::bar(B2{});  // foo() not defined
    Bar<A1>::bar(B3{});  // foo() not defined [note: argument constness]
    Bar<A2>::bar(B3{});  // foo() not defined
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if the type is streamable or not, you can have something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T> 
concept Streamable = requires (T x, std::ostream &os) { os << x; };

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo const& obj) {
    // write obj to stream
    return os;
}

template <Streamable T>
std::string to_string(T t) {
    std::stringstream ret;
    ret << t;
    return ret.str();
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    to_string(f);
    to_string(b); // error

    return 0; 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:31,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:31,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Csstream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+%0Aconcept+Streamable+%3D+requires+(T+x)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+x%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Foo+%7B%7D%3B%0Astruct+Bar+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Astd::ostream%26+operator%3C%3C(std::ostream%26+os,+Foo+const%26+obj)+%7B%0A++++//+write+obj+to+stream%0A++++return+os%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3CStreamable+T%3E%0Astd::string+to_string(T+t)+%7B%0A++++std::stringstream+ret%3B%0A++++ret+%3C%3C+t%3B%0A++++return+ret.str()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Foo+f%3B%0A++++Bar+b%3B%0A%0A++++to_string(f)%3B%0A++++to_string(b)%3B+//+error%0A%0A++++return+0%3B+%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Thank you for your insanely fast answer. It works, because in this case we have an object `std::cout`. I tried to do `stringstream ret; ret << a;` inside the concept definition, but that doesn't work. How does your solution in the more general case, when an object is not readily availible?

Comment: @Carucel you can have something like `template <typename T> 
concept Streamable = requires (T x) { std::stringstream() << x; };`